# In jsf how integer properties get value 0 in client page without process validation phase for first time request

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a bean as shown

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Demo {
private int value1;
private String value2;

..getter and setter..
```

this is my xhtml page demo.xhtml

```
<h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="id"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{demo.value1}"></p:inputText>
        <p:outputLabel value="name"></p:outputLabel>
        <p:inputText value="#{demo.value2}"></p:inputText>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

how the integer value get 0 value in the client page
[image]

i have read that in request processing lifecycle, for first time request, **jsf runtime will create new view and directly goes to render phase**. how values are set to client page without process validation phase.

i read these lines from jsf 2.0 complete reference

```
*Initial request to view the register.xhtml page

Since this
is an initial request (also referred to as a “non-postback” request) to view the
registration page, the Restore View phase creates an empty View (UIViewRoot)
component tree and stores it in the FacesContext instance.
```

After the View is created, the lifecycle immediately proceeds directly to the Render
Response phase
, since there was no incoming field data in the request to validate or
    process (also referred to as a “non-postback” request).*

i think this sentence help to understand my question. expect answer in lifecycle point of view

Answer (score 9):

Your first Problem is that `int` cannot be null, it is a primitive. Use Integer instead.

Following your will run into a problem that is related to several posts here that are around `COERCE_TO_ZERO`.

To prevent this behaviour you can configure the context parameter [javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html#javax_faces_INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL) in your web.xml to be true

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Additionally you may need to add a VM parameter to the startup script of your tomcat.
`-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false`

There are several good write-ups on the web about this topic

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)
- [JSF input - empty value converted to Zero](http://www.codereye.com/2009/05/jsf-empty-value-converted-to-zero.html)

Comment: yes u r correct, using default constructor, properties are initialized. but my question is how values are set to client page without process validation phase, note: this is first time request

Comment: @vijayakumar He answered your question... `int`s cannot be `null`. They always need to have a value, by default that's 0. But even if you use `Integer`, they will be `null` initially, but then coerced to `0` unless you explicitly disable it. This is a problem independend from JSFs lifecycle.

Comment: ok i think i need to workout jsf lifecycle again.

Comment: @noone The question didn't concern the way empty string will be treated during a postback. The question was, literally, "why do I get 0 when i bind a value to an uninitialized int field in a fresh view". Although I find the answer helpful, it does not concern the question at all, beside the last paragraph. Сheffe, you don't need to give helpful advice in an answer, you need to answer a given question instead.

Comment: @skuntsel you are right, but I have seen this several times during my work, when colleagues stumbled over this. The coerce_to_zero will be the next and harder to find question. Usually those colleagues changed their controller attributes from and to int/Integer to understand what is going on.

Comment: I have swapped it, to make the problem of int vs Integer clear.

Comment: @cheffe Thanks, it's better now! I do admit that failure to know this will yield the next "Why do I have 0/empty string in my managed bean" question, but the question nowhere states that as a problem. So it should be a side note but not the actual answer.

Comment: i updated my question.pls refer

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the default value of an `int` field is `0`. More info about this you can find in the Java Language Specification [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5).

If you want to display an empty field you have to use the `Integer` wrapper type instead of the simple `int` type. This way the initial value of the field will be null and it will be displayed as an empty field.

Comment: yes u r correct, using default constructor, properties are initialized. but my question is how values are set to client page without process validation phase, note: this is first time request

Comment: Default value of `Integer` class is `null`, as you stated further. Please do not confuse beginners with `int`/`Integer` distinction. Correct your answer and I'll reverse my vote.

Comment: Cannot understand exactly what do you want me to correct.

Comment: @AdrianMitev Have corrected the vagueness of `int`/`Integer` distinction on my own. Feel free to correct it the way you want!

Answer (score 1):

Java primitives can't be `null`, objects on the other hand can be. Your `private int value1;` simply is treated as `private int value1 = 0;` by the compiler according to section 4.12.5 of the Java language specification "Initial Values of Variables", as the default value for `int` values is `0`. Accordingly, your string's default value is `null`.

Hence, you get `value1` as zero and `value2` as a null string.

It's also worth noting it has nothing to do with JSF as its just a basic Java issue.

Comment: getting zero is not my problem, if i give any values to String property, it also displays in client page. my doubt is on jsf lifecycle. i updated the question pls refer that

Comment: @vijayakumar Your question concerns JSF lifecycle **in no way**. You request to understand why you are getting 0 in your view. It has nothing to do with lifecycle. As to the lifecycle, when an initial HTTP request is fired indeed only two phases are passed.

Comment: ...sorry what i thought is ..property values are applied to inputcomponent in applyrequestvalue phase, but in render phase only property values are called using getter method.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use Integer wrapper type instead of int primitive, only the display field would be NULL. However, if you don't supply any value to it i.e if the field is left blank, JSF again appends zero to the field implicitly.